# Filtering inbound traffic without knowing the destination subnet

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump, packet-capture, filtering

I have a linux machine configured as a router with two interfaces facing LAN A and LAN B. I want to filter traffic passing from LAN A to LAN B (inbound traffic) using tcpdump, but I don't have the subnet information of the LANs (not this: dst net subnetB)?

Comment: Never heard of Wireshark?

Comment: As I know in wireshark, we choose one interface and then we apply filter. How can I filter inbound traffic?

Comment: As I read [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2850109&group_id=53067&atid=469577), "it's impossible to dump a single interface and know the direction".

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand what you want, but if you want to capture packets that are forwarded (as in, routed) by the kernel from interface `eth0` to interface `eth1`, you can add this `iptables` rule :

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j NFLOG
```

Then, use `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to capture packets from the Netfilter Log pseudo-interface (`tcpdump` works by using `nflog` as the interface name), which reads the packets that are seen by the `NFLOG` target.

If you also want to log packets that goes the other way around, just insert another iptables rule:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j NFLOG
```

Only packets that are actually forwarded can be seen from wireshark/tcpdump. Packets that are sent from the host, or are received without being forwarded are not captured. But you can still decide to capture them by adding more NFLOG rules in `INPUT` or `OUTPUT`.

Also, watch out for the CPU usage: it can be slower to use `NFLOG` than to capture directly from an interface.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I want to count the number of new src/dst IP addresses passing from one side to other side of my router in time intervals. I need to know the direction of packets. Not the client/server direction. So I thought if I filter the incoming packets, I can count them. Is there a better way?